# Encapsulating Internal Data Structure from Clients : Changing List to Map

Tags: oop

I am working on a legacy code, where Configuration interface looks like following:

```
public interface Configuration {
    public List<ConfigurationData> configurationDataList;
}
```

As of now there is only 1 client using Configuration, but different clients will start using it in near future. I can also foresee enriched configuration which cannot be put in List, I may need to store in Map, let's say.

As my refactor exercise, I want to encapsulate internal data type of Configuration, so that even if I change **`List<>`** to **`Map<>`** it doesn't affect existing client.

Please let me know best practices around this.

Comment: Dah, you can just provide getter/setter and 99% of programmers will tell you that it's cool design. Tell more about clients. How they will use this  interface? Why currently it's a list? What is a  typical operations?

Comment: Clients are different systems within company. 
List<ConfigurationData> is list of dependencies which needs to be satisfied, but it can change such that dependency have their own dependencies. Clients retrieves this configuration and run their custom logic based on this it. 
I agree, I am thinking out loud and getter/setter looked good to me as well at first :-). I want expert's opinion on how this kind of configuration can be loosely coupled with clients.

Comment: Again, its too  broad topic. Add definition of `ConfigurationData`, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're Map structure remains flat you can add the Map as an additional accessor, and refactor the List accessor so that it just flattens the values in the map. This way you don't double up your data and it just becomes a different shape.

From a practices point of view, it probably a good idea to mark the List as deprecated to discourage people from using it. This way you have a couple of versions before you can retire it.

You can "safely" drop the List when you next update the major version, when there is some other breaking change.